# Display a TR element if a specific option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<tr class="swpm-registration-interest-row">
  <td>
    <label for="interest">
      <?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Interest'); ?>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="regular-text" name="interest" id="interest" onchange="displayInfoBoxes(this);">
      <?php echo SwpmUtils::interest_dropdown($interest) ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="swpm-registration-experience-row" style="display:none;">
  <td>
    <label for="experience" style="position: absolute;">
      <?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Experience') ?>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <textarea name="experience" style="padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #333 !important;" cols="40" rows="10" id="experience"><?php echo esc_attr($experience); ?></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not sure whether I should be doing a jQuery or PHP function here, but I have three option values:

```
Viewer
Guest
Actor
```

I wish to display the table row with a class of `swpm-registration-experience-row` when `Actor` is the selected option.

Any ideas which to use and the syntax required?

Comment: Why would php be a choice?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can hook to the `change` event of the select, and then use `val()` to check the chosen value, before using `toggle()` to show/hide the `tr` as needed. Try this:

```js
$('#interest').change(function() {
  $('.swpm-registration-experience-row').toggle($(this).val() == 'Actor');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="swpm-registration-interest-row">
    <td>
      <label for="interest">
      <?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Interest'); ?>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="regular-text" name="interest" id="interest">
        <option>Viewer</option>
        <option>Guest</option>
        <option>Actor</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="swpm-registration-experience-row" style="display:none;">
    <td>
      <label for="experience" style="position: absolute;">
      <?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Experience') ?>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="experience" style="padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #333 !important;" cols="40" rows="10" id="experience"><?php echo esc_attr($experience); ?></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working well, if I wanted to expand it slightly to include the dropdown option of "Supplier" as well. If I try the following, the "Acting" part will not then work. ```
$('select#interest').change(function() {
  $('.swpm-registration-experience-row').toggle($(this).val() == 'Acting');
  $('.swpm-registration-experience-row').toggle($(this).val() == 'Supplier');
});```

Comment: In that case you'd need to put both conditions in a single `toggle()` call: `.toggle($(this).val() == 'Acting' || $(this).val() == 'Supplier');`